# Angular Calendar is not working in different timezones with daylight savings

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-calendar

I am using angular-calendar to show the time in week view where I can drag and drop and customize the timings. Here is the sample code below from angular calendar:-
Note that this only happening when I am using drag and drop option with this settings [hourSegmentTemplate]="weekViewHourSegmentTemplate" in different timezones.

```
<mwl-calendar-week-view
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [headerTemplate]="headerTemplate"
    [hourSegments]="1"
    [hourSegmentHeight]="30"
    [hourSegmentTemplate]="weekViewHourSegmentTemplate"
    [weekStartsOn]="weekStartsOn"
    [currentTimeMarkerTemplate]="currentTimeMarkerTemplate"
    (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    (eventTimesChanged)="handleEditEvent($event)"
    (hourSegmentClicked)="dayClicked($event)"
    [dayStartHour]="0"
    [dayEndHour]="23"
  >
  </mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

The question is angular calendar is showing incorrect calendar time in different timezone in the layout.

for example:

- 12 am
- 1 am
- 2 am
- 3 am
- 3 am
- 4 am
- 5 am
  ....

Here as you can see 3am comes twice in the calendar layout.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

And my current timezone settings is [image: My current device timezone settings in windows]

For this issue the angular events are giving me the incorrect values.

Points to be noted:

- this is happening only when i am using 'automatic daylight savings' "ON" in my settings.
  to reproduce this issue in your windows machine follow this steps below:
- Go to your time settings.
- Use the timezone (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
- make this option "ON" for "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically"
- go to this url in angular-calendar library `https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/drag-to-create-events`
- Now you will be able to see the same issue in the angular-calendar library itself[image: Angular calendar itself is showing error]

Please let me know how to customize or fix this issue! Thanks.